# Existence of irreducible Polynomials in finite fields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I want to prove that **given K a finite field and n>0, exists an irreducible polynomial f ∈ K[x] of degree n.**

I am taking into account this explanation given in Field Theory by Roman: [image]

But I don't understand the implications given.

My attempt is to use the fact that a finite field extension (finite degree) of a finite field is simple and then work from there but I don't get it. Also, the notation of extension using < confuses me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Galois Fields and no general finite fields" Galois Field is synonymous with finite field. The two terms mean the same thing.

Comment: @Arthur Oh ok, thank you. Also GF(q) < GF(q^d) is the same as GF(q) : GF(q^d)?

Comment: I read "the extension $GF(q)<GF(q^m)$" as "the extension $GF(q^m)$ over $GF(q)$", which is to say, $GF(q^m)$ is particularly considered as a field extension of $GF(q)$. Whatever symbols you personally prefer to use for this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known (i.e. in every introduction text) that $\operatorname{GF}(p^r)$ consists of all the roots of the polynomial $X^{p^r} - X \in \Bbb F_p[X]$ in some algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_p$.

Therefore, $\operatorname{GF}(p^r) \setminus \{0\}$ consists of all the $(p^r-1)$<sup>st</sup> roots of unity, and a primitive $(p^r-1)$<sup>st</sup> root of unity $\zeta$ exists by a simple combinatorial argument, so $\operatorname{GF}(p^r)$ is generated by $\zeta$ as a field.

Therefore, any (finite) extension of finite fields is simple (just take $\zeta$).

Comment: What about irreducible polynomials...?

Comment: Right. Indeed, take any eement of the big field that’s not in any of the smaller fields. Since there’s exactly one of each possible cardinality, a simple counting argument tells you that there will be lots of generators of the big field over the small...

Comment: you caught a missing point, @paulgarrett , that the minimal polynomial of that generating element will have the right degree.